# In general, will increasing the number of shards utilize more CPU?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

Right now I have 5 nodes and indices are set to 5 shards and 1 replica. Shards are generally around 4 gigs.

Performance is good and CPU utilization is low, no heap or memory issues, and IO wait is acceptable, but sometimes if I search back very far in kibana it times out. When it times out CPU doesn't spike and the load avg on the nodes doesn't blow up.

The nodes have 8 cores and cpu avgs around only 3%.

So I know there is added overhead of more shards but I have the capacity for handling that i think.

My question is will more shards improve query performance by opening up more threads? I know I shouldn't manually tweak the thread pool settings so I was thinking about increasing the number of shards. Essentially I see big queries time out and I also see underutilized resources so I want to tweak it to maximize those resources.

Comment: Yes, each shard is its own Lucene index and will consume additional memory and CPU.

Comment: How many indices do you currently have?

Comment: If I search back more than about 6-7 indices it will sometimes time out